# Avoid deadlock for concurrent delete

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock

I have a table called `Products` with many columns. It is a temporary table used for reporting purposes. The data will be processed to this table concurrently by multiple user requests. There are separate stored procedures to make DML operations to this table.

Table Structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Products (
  instance uniqueidentifier,
  inserted datetime,
  col1, 
  col2,
  ...
)
```

The `inserted` column will be populated with `GETDATE()` to contain the time when each row was inserted and the `instance` column will contain the value from `newid()`. One user request will have one unique id but may have million rows. The below are the queries which will be executed concurrently, which causing the deadlock. Please advise me

Query 1:

```sql
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED 
DELETE P 
FROM Products (NOLOCK) 
WHERE instance = 'XXXX-xxx-xxx-xx'
```

Query 2:

```sql
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED 
DELETE P 
FROM Products (NOLOCK) 
WHERE inserted <= DATEADD(hh, -10, GETDATE())
```

Note: The nonclustered index is created on instance column.

Please advice me which lock I can use in this scenario.

Note I couldnt able to primary key as it is consuming time when I insert 10 million rows to the table (this for one transaction; there are 20 concurrent transations). 
The report should be generated sooner. And my procedure has multiple 35 DML statments, there are around 15 DELETE statements for instance column with other columns( `DELETE FROM table WHERE instance = @instance AND col1 = @col1`).

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952137/multi-threading-c-sharp-application-with-sql-server-database-calls/10035988#10035988

Answer (score 7):

(1) You should stop using `read uncommitted` isolation. Use at least `read committed`.

(2) There are a number of things you could try to avoid deadlocks, like ensuring your different transactions access database objects in the same order, etc. This would be worth a read - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/169960

(3) Disable lock escalation for your table (more granular locks so better concurrency, but more lock overhead):

```
ALTER TABLE Products SET (lock_escalation = disable)
```

(4) Disallow Page Locks, and allow Row Locks on your indexes (will mean you can't defrag indexes, but you can still rebuild them):

```
ALTER INDEX [<YourIndex>] ON Product WITH (allow_row_locks = on, allow_page_locks = off)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, there's no lock that you can take on these delete statements besides an exclusive lock.  Your [isolation level and `NOLOCK` hints are being ignored by Sql Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213026%28v=sql.80%29.aspx):

> (Nolock) Only applies to the `SELECT` statement.

Two suggestions:

Change your non-clustered index on `instance` to a clustered index.  BUT, only do this if you can change `NEWID()` to [`NEWSEQUENTIALID()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx).

Second, instead of performing a `delete` to remove records older than 10 hours... consider [implementing rolling partitions](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/sql-server-table-partitioning-tutorial-videos-and-scripts/).  This will remove any contention caused by the cleanup with your other `delete` operations.