# Creating multiple db connections to get data in Parallel in C# asp.net entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, task-parallel-library

I have a scenario, where in I have to fetch 18000 records from db, and convert it into a DTO. The total number of refIds = 18000 unique ids of the reference table in database.

```cs
int batchSize = 1000;
var refBatchList = new List<List<int>>();

for (var i = 0; i < refIds.Count; i += batchSize)
{
    refBatchList.Add(refIds.Skip(i).Take(batchSize).ToList());
}


var dbDataRetrievalTasks =  refBatchList.Select(async refIdsBatch => await GetReferencesAsync(refIdsBatch, new data.Entities()));
var results = await Task.WhenAll(dbDataRetrievalTasks);
```

The above section of code, creates multiple tasks which gets executed in parallel and calls the below method that retrieves data from db asynchronously.

```cs
private async Task<List<reference>> GetReferencesAsync(List<int> ids, JIVE.data.Entities db)
{
    var result = await db.Set<reference>()
        .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.reference_id))
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToListAsync();
    return result;
}
```

My question is, Since I am planning to make db calls in parallel, I am using multiple db connections. In these scenario, there would be 18 different db connections as there are 18 batches.

So I am wondering is it okay to retrieve data like this from database. what are the cons that are associated with this method? Is there any better way to achieve this.

I know if there more batches, tasks.whenAll() would create multiple tasks which could throttle the thread pool. But in my scenario the maximum batch that I could get is 20.

Comment: Single User System? Concurrent Connections to a db are typically limited on the server side by the concrete server at hand. So look into the documentation of your database product if you easily outrun the maximum connection limit. And test if doing it concurrently on the same relation against your specific database actual helpful and not hurting performance for this task or any other users needing data from that relation also.

Comment: `new data.Entities()` - in general it is recommended to dispose the contexts so refactor a bit.

Comment: As for the question - it depends what and how often the method is called. For example if you have a relatively loaded endpoint the actual performance (throughput) gains can be small - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44149141/2501279). So basically you need to measure on your workloads.

Answer (score 1):

For larger sets of IDs, have a look at AsQueryableValues(set) (https://github.com/yv989c/BlazarTech.QueryableValues) which utilizes OPENJSON behind the scenes. This would allow you to reasonably retrieve the desired 18k rows in one call.

```
var references = db.Set<reference>()
    .Where(x => db.AsQueryableValues(refIds).Contains(x.reference_id))
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync();
```

This could be improved further in a Read scenario by projecting to to a view model / DTO with just the columns you need from the reference. (For instance if References are a significant # of columns of various sizes but you only need a handful of columns)

Comment: EF 8 should already be using json.

Comment: Yes, if the OP is running .Net Core 8 & EF 8 then EF will pass contains sets as JSON so less need to split up filter sets, and no need for a third party library like QueryableValues.

Comment: I just updated my test projects to EF Core 8 and yeah, comparing against in-memory lists is now done with `JSONOpen()` so that is a seriously nice improvement. If you get an error about "'$' symbol not recognized" check that your database isn't set up for an older version compatibility. Not sure how or why but my test database on SQL Server 2022 was set up for 2008 compatibility. Support for JSONOpen was introduced with SQL Server 2016.